# Magento2 - Setup Compile Error - Class Not_Existing_Class does not exist

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.0

I installed magento 2 Community version successfully. Now when i try to upgrade the setup i get the error **Please re-run Magento compile command**.

So i ran the compile command

```
magento setup:di:compile
```

but i am getting this error

```
Area configuration aggregation... 5/7 [====================>-------]  71% 35 min
s 736.2 MiB

  [ReflectionException]
  Class Not_Existing_Class does not exist


  [ReflectionException]
  Class Not_Existing_Class does not exist
```

Any ideas as to how this can be resolved ?!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a temporary fix, i was able to resolve this problem by commenting following line:

```
 \Not_Existing_Class $notExistingClass
```

in **<< Magento2 Root Folder >>\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Test\Unit\Generator\TestAsset\TestGenerationClass.php**

I have also reported the issue on GitHub here and awaiting the community's response: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2404